# Eclipse search and replace appears to malfunction with empty space

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I had a baffling thing happen with search-and-replace in a .py file (using PyDev).

I copy-pasted some code from a PDF book and then found that this process had seemingly inserted a space at the start of all the lines. Getting rid of this space manually would have been irksome so I assumed that Find/Replace would work, with "Regular expressions" ticked:

Find: `^(\s*)(.*)$`

Replace with: `$2`

... but it didn't: it behaved as though there was a reluctant quantifier, i.e. as though I had done this:

Find: `^(\s*?)(.*)$`

... i.e. `$2` in fact captured the entire line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

By copy-pasting, what had been inserted at the start of the line turned out not to be a space but a [non-breaking space](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0), Unicode AA0A.

To my surprise, the regex handling in Eclipse's Find/Replace appears not to consider this to be "white space". A quick search suggests that this is in fact in accordance with normal (all?) regex handling.

I thought I'd put this here in case anyone else gets caught by this. To inspect anything suspicious and find out what actual Unicode you've got you can copy it and paste it [here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%C2%A0), for example.

Comment: Of course, a non-breaking space is not whitespace and [does not behave like whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), it just looks like a space. This is well documented: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29

Comment: @howlger As I say, no-one else came up with this suggestion when I first described the issue. You can give all the links you want, this undoubtedly qualifies as a puzzler: it looks like a normal space and behaves substantially, although not entirely, like a normal space. It can quite legitimately be argued that a NBS *should* be treated as white space. Indeed there are several other Unicode characters, e.g. zero-width space, U+200B, for which the same could be argued.

Comment: The meaning of `\s` is specified as `A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), how could one have known that you had mistaken non-breaking spaces for spaces?

Comment: Not everyone knows everything about regex rules, or about quantum physics. They learn as they go along. That will have been your case. An MRE? Are you serious? This was never a programming problem. No-one could have known about anything. Which is precisely why I have put this answer out for someone slightly below me on the regex/Eclipse/Unicode learning curve who has the misfortune to stumble on this.

Comment: The Javadoc link is for those who want to know the details. Yes, I don't think the question makes much sense without a reproducible example, but I wasn't the one who downvoted (IMHO downvoting should not be allowed; instead, people should just tell what they think what's wrong; but if they tell, they shouldn't get a response like _"An MRE? Are you serious?"_ either).